# Unity3D - Is it possible to set properties of an animation clip through script?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have a cube. When it spawns, it animates from a scale of 0, to a scale of 5, giving it the effect that it is growing.

I have around 100 cubes being spawned into my scene. I want the max scale of each cube to be a different size (for a bit of variety), but because of the animation clip attached to my cube prefab, the max size of the cube will be 5 (see picture).

Is there a way through code or other means where I can set the scale property of the animation to be random? I've tried using `Animator`, `AnimationClip` and `Animation` but they have no methods or variables about setting a property size.

[image]

Comment: Just a quick side note here: If you want to animate `Transform`-specific (or any other value) you might consider using [DOTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but no.

The "yes" here is that there is a series of calls you can make that will get you the data and modify it, *but* the modification is only allowed as an Editor script: you can't modify the values in the runtime player environment.

See the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip.SetCurve.html

> **Note: SetCurve will only work at runtime for legacy animation clips. For non-legacy AnimationClips it is an editor-only function.**
>
> The following script example shows how a GameObject position can be animated using an animation clip. An animated curve is set onto the AnimationClip using SetCurve(). This example moves the x offset from 1.0 down to 0.0.
>
> ```
> using UnityEngine;
> using System.Collections;
>
> [RequireComponent(typeof(Animation))]
> public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
>     public Animation anim;
>     void Start() {
>         anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
>         AnimationCurve curve = AnimationCurve.Linear(0.0F, 1.0F, 2.0F, 0.0F);
>         AnimationClip clip = new AnimationClip();
>         clip.legacy = true;
>         clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition.x", curve);
>         anim.AddClip(clip, "test");
>         anim.Play("test");
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: @Tom I almost gave up, as I was digging through the Animation class and wasn't finding what I wanted, ended up on an introduction page which *did* list the values I was interested in, and was able to work backwards, then found that note.

Comment: Can we set anything but float with this? How to create a series of changing sprite for instance?

Comment: @JeromeJ I don't know, I haven't messed around with it myself. My guess is *probably.* Try it and report back!

Comment: @Draco18s I didn't manage to use anything but floats using the legacy animation clips. It's possible to do more with the `UnityEditor.AnimationUtility` but as the name suggest you can't use it during runtime. If you only want to dynamically create a sprite-based animations as I needed, it's pretty easy to recode it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alterative to solve your problem without much complications. It doesn't touch animation by code.

Here are the facts that I understand:

1. You have an animation that makes your cube grow.
2. You want to reuse that animation on all cubes, no matter their max size.
3. You want your cubes to be a random max size.

## Solution

Here is the solution I propose:

#### 1. Make your cube have a parent object.

Let's call it "CubeParent", and the child will be named "Cube". Make sure both objects' scale is set to 1.

Your object hierarchy should look like this:

```
CubeParent
- Cube
```

#### 2. Make your animation change the Cube's scale from 0 to 1

Make sure your animation is affecting the "Cube" object, NOT the "CubeParent".
We are making it grow to 1, but don't worry, we'll get it work for all sizes.

That 1 represents the full size of the "CubeParent". We'll use that to our advantage later.

#### 3. Spawn cubes with random sizes

When you spawn a new Cube, to modify its max size to whatever you want it to be, modify the scale of the "CubeParent" object.

This way, your animation will grow the "Cube" from 0 to 1, where 1 represents the full size of the "CubeParent". If your "CubeParent" is larger, your cube grow animation will be proportional.